# Looping through dates in R

Tags: r, loops, date

I'm trying to create a loop for start and end date to run this function:

```
startdates <- c("2003-10-01", "2004-10-01", "2005-10-01", "2006-10-01", "2007-10-01", 
"2008-10-01", "2009-10-01", 
"2010-10-01", "2011-10-01", "2012-10-01", "2013-10-01", "2014-10-01", "2015-10-01", 
"2016-10-01","2017-10-01", "2018-10-01", "2019-10-01")

enddates <- c("2004-09-30", "2005-09-30", "2006-09-30", "2007-09-30", "2008-09-30", 
"2009-09-30","2010-09-30", "2011-09-30", "2012-09-30", "2013-09-30", "2014-09-30", 
"2015-09-30", "2016-09-30","2017-09-30", "2018-09-30", "2019-09-30", "2020-09-30")

for(i in dates) {
  statsOutput <- FUNCTIONHERE(siteNumber = "xxx",
                                  startDate = startdates,
                                  endDate = enddates)
}
```

I'm not sure how to set up this loop so that it will take the start date and end date in my vectors (startdates and enddates). I can't list the function I'm using, but it takes a siteNumber, goes into the web to grab data for that site and then uses the startDate and endDate to know which date range to grab.

Comment: To make this reproducible you should provide a function that can be used.since all posts to the SO [tag:r] tag should be repr4oducible.  The function does not have to be what you have but can be some simple function.  In my answer I used `paste`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could loop over the sequence of either one of those (assuming both have the same `length`).  Use the index to subset the corresponding 'startdates', 'enddates' within the loop and store the output in a `list`

```
statsOutput <- vector('list', length(startdates))
for(i in seq_along(startdates)) {
    statsOutput[[i]] <-  FUNCTIONHERE(siteNumber = "xxx",
                                  startDate = startdates[i],
                                  endDate = enddates[i])
}
```

---

Or it may be easier with `Map`

```
statsOutput <- Map(FUNCTIONHERE, startDate = startdates, endDate = enddates,
         MoreArgs = list(siteNumber = "xxx"))
```

Comment: I used your code for step 1 of what I need to do and it worked. But now I am stuck with trying to perform this:  for(i in 1:17) {
  
  floodThresh_west_POR3_2[[i]] <- FUNCTIONHERE(dailyQClean_west_POR3_2[i][c("date","discharge")],
                                                    peakFlows_west_POR3_2[i][c("peak_dt","peak_va")])
  
}  I get an error that says Error in x[, 1:2] : incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: Just updated it sorry! my dailyQClean_west_POR3_2 and peakFlows_west_POR3_2 each have 17 dataframes within it called [[1]], [[2]], etc.

Comment: What are these `dailyQClean_west_POR3_2` and `peakFlows_west_POR3_2`.  If they are list elements, you need `[[i]]` instead of `[i]` because `[i]` will still be a list where as `[[i]]` extract the data.frame element from the list

Answer (score 1):

We will use `paste` as the function `fun` to make this executable.  Replace that with whatever you have.

`out` will be a list of the results.  If `fun` creates scalars and you want a vector result replace `Map` with `mapply`.

```
yr <- 2003:2019
st <- paste0(yr, "-01-01")
en <- paste0(yr, "-09-30")
fun <- paste
out <- Map(fun, "xxx", st, en, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```